# After core update: Access denied after submitting form

Tags: 7, webforms

We’re running on Drupal 7.73 and WebForm 7.x-3.30 – for a while now since the 7.75 to 7.77 Drupal release, we’ve been unable to update Drupal successfully.

As every time a user submits a form on the site, we’re getting an “Access Denied” message.

If you’re logged in as Admin it works. I believe it could have something to do with the “success message” that’s being displayed and that in theory, a redirect to a success page could fix it.
However, as we have many forms across several sites, it is not practical to go this route.

For two years we have had no problem updating Drupal to latest and no issues with WebForm so this is a new issue.

Can you please assist in providing a solution for this as we are unable to update to implement latest security fixes?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions page to see if there are any Webform permissions you haven't configured?

Comment: Yes, it is set to allow Anonymous posts - which is correct

Comment: Does anyone have some insight into this?
We really need this problem resolved...

Comment: You should try to isolate the issue first. Check a clean Drupal 7.77 and webform 3.30 installation and see if the issue exists there. If not then you have something else causing your access problems in your particular site. We have no information on that so we can't help you. If you can reproduce this on a fresh install then it's clearly a major bug in the module and needs to be reported on the module issue queue and get it resolved through regular channels. I can see you already opened an issue but you haven't isolated the problem yet from what I can see.

Comment: If you can't reproduce your issue on a fresh install, then I would suggest you try to turn off your custom modules and see if that resolves the issue, if not then try your custom themes, then other contrib modules etc and find the cause. You can also use step debuggers like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). I don't have a Drupal 7 installation at hand but you could search for `module_invoke('access'` to see where `hook_access` is called from and set a breakpoint there I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Beebee. Doing a fresh install is not practical at the moment. But I will do it once I've run out of potential fixes to try.
For now, I'll be attempting to implement this patch. Hopefully it works.
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_service/issues/2048343#comment-9331515

Comment: Cool so it looks like it's connected with another webform related module called webform_service? Good that you found the root cause